# Is there a function to get the cell your equation is pointing at as the output rather than the value inside the cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For example if I had an function such as vlookup that put me into a cell could I then have another function that gives what cell it found rather then the value inside the cell?

Comment: Do you mean the actual cell address, e.g. A1? Can you give an example of the type of formula you're currently using?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of "lookup" functions.  One will find the location of something, the other will return the contents of that location.  A function like VLOOKUP will return the contents.  A function like MATCH will return a location.

If you are looking specifically to mirror the results (find the location of the cell that VLOOKUP returns), you can do that.  VLOOKUP does a search in one column and then follows your specifications for how many columns away to return an answer from.  You could point to the same search cell with MATCH, then apply the same offset to the answer that you specified for VLOOKUP.